# Walk function in Arcpy

Tags: arcpy, walk

I posted a similar question before, but I am trying to list all of the element types in the geodatabase, such as feature datasets, networks, rasters, domains, non-spatial tables, etc.

For rasters, I got the following code working.

```
#Get Raster datasets
rasters = arcpy.ListRasters()

for rs in rasters:
    arcpy.AddMessage(rs)
```

However, I was told that I should probably use `Walk` function instead of `ListFeature` function. The following is the the sample code I found, but was unable to find a way to print the result.

*What change do I need to make to the following code to make it print results?*

```
workspace = "c:/data"
rasters = []

walk = arcpy.da.Walk(workspace, topdown=True, datatype="RasterDataset")

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in walk:
    # Disregard any folder named 'back_up' in creating list of rasters
    if "back_up" in dirnames:
        dirnames.remove('back_up')
    for filename in filenames:
        rasters.append(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))
```

Comment: Are you looking for something other than `print(rasters)`?

Comment: Oh I just found out I can simply use arcpy.Addmessage to print my result on ArcGIS. I cannot believe how dumb I am,but thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To address your broader question, you could create a report based on the information in [`arcpy.da.Describe`](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/data-access/describe.htm) (ArcGIS Pro only I think, but you can use the older [`arcpy.Describe`](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-functions/describe.htm) object in ArcMap, though the syntax is different).

In the example below, I use `walk` to find everything (not looking *just* for rasters or feature classes), then use `arcpy.da.Describe` to get detailed info about each element including datatype, then use a dictionary to group by datatype:

```
import os
from collections import defaultdict 


def domain_report(gdb):
    domains = arcpy.da.ListDomains(gdb)
    report = []
    if bool(domains):
        report += ["Domain:"]

    for domain in domains:
        report += [f'\t\t{domain.name}: {domain.domainType}']
        if domain.domainType == 'CodedValue':
            coded_values = domain.codedValues
            for val, desc in coded_values.items():
                report += [f'\t\t\t\t{val}: {desc}']
        elif domain.domainType == 'Range':
            report += [f'\t\t\t\t{domain.range[0]} - {domain.range[1]}']

    return report


def data_report(gdb):

    elements = defaultdict(list)

    walk = arcpy.da.Walk(gdb, topdown=True)

    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in walk:
        for dirname in dirnames:  # 'FeatureDataset'
            desc = arcpy.da.Describe(os.path.join(dirpath, dirname))
            elements[desc['dataType']].append(desc)

        for filename in filenames:
            desc = arcpy.da.Describe(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))
            elements[desc['dataType']].append(desc)

    report = []

    for element_type, element_list in elements.items():
        report += [f"{element_type}:"]
        for element_description in element_list:
            report +=  [f"\t\t{element_description['catalogPath']}"] # Here I just output the path, but there's lots more info in the Describe object

    return report

gdb = r"D:\Temp\SampleData.gdb"

report = domain_report(gdb) + data_report(gdb)
arcpy.AddMessage('\n'.join(report))
print('\n'.join(report))
```

Example output:

```
Domain:
        dAccessControl: CodedValue
                1: Full Access Control
                2: Partial Access Control
                3: No Access Control
FeatureDataset:
        D:\Temp\SampleData.gdb\TestFeatureDataset
FeatureClass:
        D:\Temp\SampleData.gdb\Centerline
        D:\Temp\SampleData.gdb\TestFeatureDataset\FCinFD
Table:
        D:\Temp\SampleData.gdb\Lrs_Metadata
RelationshipClass:
        D:\Temp\SampleData.gdb\Redline__ATTACHREL
RasterDataset:
        D:\Temp\SampleData.gdb\TestRaster
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import arcpy
import os

#Set a workspace 
workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

#Get Featureclasse
walk = arcpy.da.Walk(workspace, datatype="FeatureClass")

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in walk:
    for filename in filenames:
        arcpy.AddMessage(filename)
```